# Formik Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, formik

I am working on EDIT formik form, this form is in form of MODAL. when setState is passed as setState(true) than form will appear. But the problem is that without clicking onClick setState is being triggerd (according to error). In form values are already passed as it is EDIT form. I changed `onClick={editStory}` to `onClick={()=> editStory()}` still error not gone

> Error: "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.
> at EditQs (webpack-internal:///./src/new-components/Projects/EditQs.js:106:23)"

MyQs2.js

```
function MyQs2({row, isItemSelected, labelId, index}) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const editStory = () => {
    console.log('editstory is triggering')
    setOpenStoryDrawer(true);
  };

  const [openStoryDrawer, setOpenStoryDrawer] = React.useState(false);
  const handleStoryDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpenStoryDrawer(false);
  };

  const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = React.useState([])
  const [allUsersObj, setAllUsersObj] = React.useState([])
  
  const [allProjects, setAllProjects] = React.useState([])
```

//Error occur in this useEffect but i need updated data to show from firestore
React.
useEffect(() => {
readAllUsers()
readAllProjects()
}, [])

```
  const readAllUsers = async()=> {

    console.log('readAllUsesrs is calling')
    try{     
     firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("role", "==", 'user')
            .onSnapshot(function (val) {
                let user = []
                 val.forEach(function(doc) {
                    user.push(doc.data().name); 
                    setAllUsers(user)
                })})
            
                   }

const readAllProjects = async() => {
      console.log('readAllUsesrs is calling')
      const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('projects').get()
      setAllProjects( snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().name) );
}

    return (
      <>
      
        <TableRow hover role="checkbox" aria-checked={isItemSelected} tabIndex={-1} key={index} selected={isItemSelected}>
          <TableCell padding="checkbox" sx={{ pl: 3 }} onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.question)}>
            <Checkbox
              color="primary"
              checked={isItemSelected}
              inputProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': labelId
              }}
            />
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell
            component="th"
            id={labelId}
            scope="row"
            onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.projects)}
            sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          >
            <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ color: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'grey.600' : 'grey.900' }}>
              {' '}
              {row.question}{' '}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="caption"> {row.projects} </Typography>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.projects}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.assignTo}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{row.priority}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">
            {row.state === "published" && <Chip label="published" size="small" chipcolor="success" />}
            {row.state === "unpublished" && <Chip label="unpublished" size="small" chipcolor="orange" />}
            {row.state === 'Active' && <Chip label="Confirm" size="small" chipcolor="primary" />}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center" sx={{ pr: 3 }}>
            <IconButton color="primary" size="large">
              <VisibilityTwoToneIcon sx={{ fontSize: '1.3rem' }} />
            </IconButton>

//below onClick is triggering
            <IconButton color="secondary" size="large" onClick={()=> editStory()} 
              <EditTwoToneIcon sx={{ fontSize: '1.3rem' }} />
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>

// This calls a EditPage
      <EditQs existingQs={row} open={openStoryDrawer} handleDrawerOpen={handleStoryDrawerOpen} allProjects={allProjects} allUsers={allUsers} />

        </>
      );
}

export default MyQs2
```

According to error appears in this Form page

EditQs.js

```
const EditQs = ({ open, handleDrawerOpen, existingQs, allProjects, allUsers }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

  const sendDataToFirestore = (item) => {
  try{
    
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('projects')
    .doc(item.projects)
    .update({
      question : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(item)
      
    }).then(
      dispatch(
        openSnackbar({
          open: true,
          message: 'New Question added',
          variant: 'alert',
          alert: {
            color: 'success'
          },
          close: false
        })
      )
      )
    }catch(err){
    console.log('an error occured', err)
}
}

  const formik = useFormik({

    enableReinitialize: true, //if i remove this, error gone but this is responsible 
for adding values in formik during render

    validateOnChange:false,
    validateOnBlur:false,
    initialValues: {
        id: existingQs.id ?  existingQs.id : '',
        question: existingQs.question?  existingQs.question : '',
        projects: existingQs.projects?  existingQs.projects : '',
        assignTo: existingQs.assignTo ?  existingQs.assignTo : '',
        priority: existingQs.priority ?  existingQs.priority : '',
        dueDate: existingQs.dueDate ? new Date(existingQs.dueDate) : new Date(),
        state: existingQs.state ?  existingQs.state : '',
        image: existingQs.image
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values,{resetForm}) => {
      const item = {
        id: values.id,
        question: values.question,
        projects: values.projects,
        assignTo: values.assignTo,
        priority: values.priority,
        dueDate: values.dueDate ? new Date(values.dueDate) : new Date(),
        state: values.state,
        image: values.image
      };
      sendDataToFirestore(item);
      () => handleDrawerOpen();
      resetForm()
      readAllProjects()
    }
  });

  return (
    <Drawer
      sx={{
        ml: open ? 3 : 0,
        flexShrink: 0,
        zIndex: 1200,
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        width: { xs: 320, md: 450 },
        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
          height: '100vh',
          width: { xs: 320, md: 450 },
          position: 'fixed',
          border: 'none',
          borderRadius: '0px'
        }
      }}
      variant="temporary"
      anchor="right"
      open={open}
      ModalProps={{ keepMounted: true }}
      onClose={() => handleDrawerOpen}
    >
      {open && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Typography variant="h4">Edit Question</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                      <Typography variant="subtitle1">Question:</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
                      <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        id="question"
                        name="question"
                        multiline
                        rows={3}
                        value={formik.values.question}
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        error={formik.touched.question && Boolean(formik.errors.question)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.question && formik.errors.question}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle1">Assign to:</Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                        <InputLabel>Choose a user</InputLabel>
                          <Select
                            id="assignTo"
                            name="assignTo"
                            displayEmpty
                            value={formik.values.assignTo}
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            label='Assign to'
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'assignTo' }}
                          >
                            {allUsers.map((val, index) => (
                              <MenuItem key={index} value={val}>
                                {val}
                              </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle1">project:</Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                        <InputLabel>Choose a Project</InputLabel>
                          <Select
                            id="projects"
                            name="projects"
                            displayEmpty
                            value={formik.values.projects}
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            label='projects'
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'projects' }}
                          >
                            {allProjects.map((val, index) => (
                              <MenuItem key={index} value={val}>
                                {val}
                              </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                      <Typography variant="subtitle1">Prioritize:</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
                      <FormControl>
                        <RadioGroup
                          row
                          aria-label="color"
                          value={formik.values.priority}
                          onChange={formik.handleChange}
                          name="priority"
                          id="priority"
                        >
                          <FormControlLabel value="low" control={<Radio color="primary" sx={{ color: 'primary.main' }} />} label="Low" />
                          <FormControlLabel
                            value="medium"
                            control={<Radio color="warning" sx={{ color: 'warning.main' }} />}
                            label="Medium"
                          />
                          <FormControlLabel value="high" control={<Radio color="error" sx={{ color: 'error.main' }} />} label="High" />
                        </RadioGroup>
                      </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle1">State:</Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                        <InputLabel >State of question</InputLabel>

                          <Select
                            id="state"
                            name="state"
                            displayEmpty
                            value={formik.values.state}
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            // label='choose question state'
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'choose question state' }}
                          >
                            {states.map((val, index) => (
                              <MenuItem key={index} value={val.title}>
                                {val.title}
                              </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <AnimateButton>
                    <Button fullWidth variant="contained" type="submit">
                      Save
                    </Button>
                  </AnimateButton>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </form>
        </Box>
      )}
    </Drawer>
  );
};

export default EditQs;
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue is `setAllUsers(readAllUsers())`. You are calling `setAllUsers` passing a function `readAllUsers` as argument but inside this function you are calling `setAllUsers` again

```
        .onSnapshot(function (val) {
            let user = []
             val.forEach(function(doc) {
                user.push(doc.data().name); 
                // setAllUsers again
                setAllUsers(user)
            })})
```

Every time you change the state, your component is getting rerendered.

It would be better to write different useEffect for each state setup. Each useEffect will have different dependentcies. Setting correct depencencies needs analysing the code. Otherwise you might not get correct state or your component might keep rerendering

Comment: I removed it but still issue exists. I write different useEffect for each function call.